# Rails is it possible to get the last record inserted into the db without requerying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link in my view that calls the method below via ajax. I'm basically trying to get the id of the record that was inserted via `@application.update_attributes(params[:application])`, but when i call `@curr_app = @application.application_field.last`, it returns the last record that was inserted before my ajax calls.

For example if i hit the page initially and say the highest id in the application_fields table is 50, when i click my ajax link, `@curr_app.id` is always 50, no matter how many times i click my ajax link.

I thought `@application.application_field.last` should get the last record in the db? How can i get the last inserted record? Do i have to re-query for it?

```
  # PUT /applications/1
  # PUT /applications/1.json
  def update
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @application.update_attributes(params[:application])

        @curr_app = @application.application_field.last
        puts @curr_app.id

        format.html { redirect_to @application, notice: 'Application was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: It depends on the database. Some support a `returning` clause, which lets you get the ID of the row just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to do

```
@application.reload
```

However, Rails caches queries during the same request processing, so it may get the result from the cache and not from database. You only have to try and see the logs to see where it gets it from.

Or maybe

```
@curr_app = ApplicationField.last
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to requery the database to get the last record.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
@app = Application.find(:last)
```

Answer (score 0):

the same variable you can use to get the id is: 
@curr_id = @application.id
its still have the json with the data untill you leave this page.

```
def update
@application = Application.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @application.update_attributes(params[:application])

    @curr_app = @application.id

    format.html { redirect_to @application, notice: 'Application was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js
  end
end
```

end